# SQL conditional aggregate

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, aggregate

I have a table:

```
items status count date
----- ------ ----- ----------
apple good   100   01/02/2017
apple good   200   03/02/2017
apple bad    50    02/02/2017
pear  good   100   04/02/2017
```

The result, i am looking is to aggregate the count based on status and display the latest date for each item:

```
items  count  date
-----  -----  ----------
apple  250    03/02/2017
pear   100    04/02/2017
```

Comment: Please tag with DB name you are using ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sum , max and group by  and a case when for sum properly good and bad

```
select items, sum(case when status = 'good' then count else -count end), max(date)
from my_table 
group by itmes
```

or if you don't need  a relative sum based on good and bad

```
select items, sum( count ), max(date)
from my_table 
group by itmes
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT items, SUM(count) count, MAX(date) date
FROM table
GROUP BY items
```

And if you want to separate sum for each status, then:

```
SELECT items, status, SUM(count) count, MAX(date) date
FROM table
GROUP BY items, status
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want:

```
select items, sum(count), max(date)
from t
group by items;
```